# PDO OCI PHP pass array parameter to stored procedure

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, pdo

I have a collection types in oracle defined like that :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "NUM_ARRAY" AS TABLE OF NUMBER(8,0)
```

and stored procedure :

```
PROCEDURE choice ( name IN VARCHAR2, order IN NUM_ARRAY )
```

How to do bind param with pdo and php like that ? :  `$stmt->bindParam(':order ',...);`

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are still looking for an answer to this question, but I will give you my answer in case others are having the same problem.  I found my answer at the following link.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html

Here is a function that I created to pass parameters to an Oracle procedure.  The procedure that I am using is not returning any results so therefore this function does not catch anything.

```
public function bindVariablesToProcedure($var1, $var2, $var3)
{
    $rtn = []; // initalize array
    if($this->dbconnect)
    {
        /* schema is your database schema
           BindVariable is your stored procedure */
        $bindSql = 'BEGIN schema.BindVariable(:var1, :var2, :var3); END;';

        /* The numbers for the fourth parameter are the character lengths
           that are in my database.  I found that without these numbers
           the "oci_bind_by_name" function would error out. */
        $bindRes = oci_parse($this->dbconnect, $bindSql);
        oci_bind_by_name($bindRes, ':var1', $var1, 100);
        oci_bind_by_name($bindRes, ':var2', $var2, 5);
        oci_bind_by_name($bindRes, ':var3', $var3, 100);

        if(oci_execute($bindRes))
        {
            $rtn['status'] = "success";
        }
        else
        {
            $e = oci_error($bindRes);  // For oci_execute errors pass the statement handle
            $rtn['bindErrorSql'] = $e['sqltext'];
            $rtn['bindErrorCode'] = $e['code'];
            $rtn['bindErrorMsg'] = $e['message'];
            $rtn['status'] = "failed";
        }
    }
    return $rtn;
}
```